# Display all product tags associated with a specific product category

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic, filters, tags

I need some help writing a shortcode to display all product tags associated with a specific product category which can be displayed on any page.

My problem is that I can display all product tags anywhere by using the below code, but I'm unable to filter those tags by a given product category:

```
function product_terms_by_cat() {       
    $terms = get_terms (
        array (
            'taxonomy' => 'product_tag', 
            'hide_empty' => false)
        );
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        echo $term->name;
    }
}       
add_shortcode('product_terms_by_cat', 'product_terms_by_cat');
```

I've tried using functions for standard WP post tags/categories but they're used within the loop (eg. category pages or single post pages) and don't help.

Could modifying the code found on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44578723/display-product-categories-based-on-tags-of-a-product-woocommerce-php) work?The code filters categories based on tags (the opposite of what I want). Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh ha! Have figured out how to do this. Here's the code for future people who are looking for the same thing:

```
function get_category_tags($args) {
    global $wpdb;
    $tags = $wpdb->get_results("
        SELECT DISTINCT terms2.term_id as tag_id, terms2.name as tag_name, terms2.slug as tag_slug, null as tag_link
        FROM
            wp_posts as p1
            LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships as r1 ON p1.ID = r1.object_ID
            LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy as t1 ON r1.term_taxonomy_id = t1.term_taxonomy_id
            LEFT JOIN wp_terms as terms1 ON t1.term_id = terms1.term_id,

            wp_posts as p2
            LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships as r2 ON p2.ID = r2.object_ID
            LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy as t2 ON r2.term_taxonomy_id = t2.term_taxonomy_id
            LEFT JOIN wp_terms as terms2 ON t2.term_id = terms2.term_id
        WHERE
            t1.taxonomy = 'product_cat' AND p1.post_status = 'publish' AND terms1.term_id IN (".$args['categories'].") AND 
            t2.taxonomy = 'product_tag' AND p2.post_status = 'publish'
            AND p1.ID = p2.ID
        ORDER by tag_name
    ");

    $count = 0;

    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
        $tags[$count]->tag_link = get_tag_link($tag->tag_id);
        $count++;
    }
    return $tags;
}

$args = array('categories'=> "YOUR PRODUCT CATEGORY ID HERE"); 
$tags = get_category_tags($args); 

foreach ($tags as $tag) {   
    echo '<a href="'.$tag->tag_link.'">' . $tag->tag_name . '</a>';  
}
```

I used this in a WP Bakery shortcode and it worked a treat. I guess you could use this wherever you would like. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

```
function product_terms_by_cat() {       
$terms = get_terms (
    array (
        'taxonomy' => 'product_category', 
        'hide_empty' => false)
    );
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    echo $term->name;
}
}       
add_shortcode('product_terms_by_cat', 'product_terms_by_cat');
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think you understood my problem. That snippet looks like it's the same as I had provided, but simply changed `'taxonomy' => 'product_tag',` to `'taxonomy' => 'product_category',`. It didn't help sorry.